# how to handle console errors when consuming api in next js

Tags: laravel, next.js

I get two errors from xhr and from the error handler javascript in the console when consuming api from laravel in my next js application. I want the error from the xhr to not be there. how to handle it?

[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4e1P.png)

front end :

```
export async function checkAuthentication() {
  const token = Cookies.get("token");
  try {
    if (token) {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BACKEND}/api/user`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            Accept: "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      if (response.ok) return true;
      return false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

backend :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getUser(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json(['user' => Auth::user()]);
    }
}
```

I want to remove errors from the xhr